# Web site with: google map like or GIS, one million record database and a feature to run advanced search

Tags: web-mapping, database, google, apache

What is the GPL way  - without or with little developing - to build a web site runnning on apache which has to feature: one million record database (MySQL; which may be editable), an advanced search on it with results (pins and/or images) to display on a google like map?

Example: http://livelovely.com/search

Comment: GPL way? :S. Use GPL software == GPL way

Answer (score 2):

The front end would be OpenLayers. The database would ideally be PostGIS but you could manage with MySQL I guess. You might want Geoserver in there too. For background data use OpenStreetMap.

http://www.osgeo.org for all things open source geo.

Answer (score 0):

A practical example of [openlayers and a database](http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/56/Openstreetmap%20-_%20_PostGIS%7CMySQL%7CSpatiaLite_%20-_%20OpenLayers_%20From%20Map%20to%20Web%20Presentation.pdf)